# Word document Author property as SharePoint column - how?

Tags: 2010, word, metadata

I would like to expose the Word document property "Author" as a SharePoint metadata column. It is clearly not linked to the "Created By" field, whose internal column name is "Author".

Is it possible to link the Word Author property to a SharePoint column? In our company, Word documents get uploaded not only by the author, but also by assistants. We'd like to retain the real author as metadata in SharePoint.

Can this be done with SharePoint Designer, i.e. without code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this: Created a new column in the library with the name "_Author" (mind the _ sign) and the data type `single line of text`. This will show the Word Author property. Good enough for me.

I also found this on the [Technet forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/00b648dc-6b9b-420d-b9eb-6ac095f6f5b2/) but I don't see a custom property "Author0" in the Word properties, so could not recreate that solution.