# Promote Word's "Company" property

Tags: content-type, word, ecm

I'm trying to promote the Microsoft Word's "Company" property.

I tried using the [technique that consists in creating a column with the same name, prefixed by an `_`](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/64689/word-document-author-property-as-sharepoint-column-how). This is working for the "Author" column but not for the "Company" column.

My investigation let me think that only properties from the "Core properties" content type can be promoted:

[image: Core properties]

But the "Company" property is part of the "Extended properties":

[image: Extended properties]

**Is it possible to promote the "Company" column, and how?**

To describe my requirement, we are migrating a bunch of network folders in several SharePoint library/site collections. Some non-technical users will dispatch the documents using a webdav drag&drop. Some metadatas within the word documents should be promoted in the SharePoint columns (I added the corresponding columns in the library).

As the documents are mostly in the legacy `.doc` format, I can't (or at least it's not simple and efficient) use the Open XML SDK to extract this content.

**In a more general way, is there any documentation somewhere that describe/explain this behavior?**